# Access ManyToMany relation from model property in Django

Tags: django

I have a Loan model that has some relationships, one of which is a many to many with a Resource model (the items our borrower is loaning). I'd like to add a derived property to the loan that does a quick check on the status of the loan's various resources. But whenever I try to access the loan's resources from within this property, I just get back None. It works fine for the one to one relationships, just not many to many.

```
class Loan(models.Model):
    borrower = models.ForeignKey('Borrower', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    resources = models.ManyToManyField('Resource', through='LoanedResource', blank=True)
    start_date = models.DateTimeField()
    due_date = models.DateTimeField()

    @property
    def is_closed(self):
        print(self.borrower) # Works!

        print(self.resources) # None :(
        print(self.loanedresources_set) # None :(

        print(LoanedResource.objects.filter(loan = self.id)) # This works, but I believe it bypasses prefetch_related, so gets really slow. 

        # Return my calculated value here
```

If this can't work, anyone have ideas on how to create derived property with many to many relationship that takes advantage of prefetch_related?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried `self.resources.all()`?

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you sir! Will mark as the answer if you want to post it

Comment: Well, if you can access `self.resources.all()` then - self.resources should not return `None` as you pointed in the comment. It should return `ManyRelatedManager` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the M2M objects as

```
self.resources.all()
```